# Unix Pattern Match for: "C:\filename.txt ->" and "C:\filename.txt\ ->"

Tags: unix, filenames

How to pattern match those in Unix?  I don't understand how do pattern match for a folder or file ending with "->"

Edit:  I'm trying to perform pattern matching with FastCopy.  I only want to copy certain files, not all.

Comment: Poor question.  I have voted to put it on hold as "unclear what you're asking".  Please [edit] it and elaborate.  Also tell us why you want to do this pattern match.  A good question is normally 50 words or more long.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to a regular expression (regex) pattern match?

If so, the following should do the trick:

```
C:\\filename\.txt(\\|)\s->
```

To match the `->` there is nothing special needed for a regex match, the right bracket can be used as-is. This will also match both filenames with or without a trailing backslash.

[Regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/) is a very helpful site were you can play around with regex. It will explain every part of the expression for you to help you learn.

It would also help if you could say what program/utility you are using to try to match with. Some programs use different variations of regex with slightly different syntax or features.

---

Edit:

According to the documentation for FastCopy, specifically regarding [pattern matching](http://ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en#wild_card) filtering, it supports only a few regex-like syntax.

It explains that if a backslash is found in the middle of the filter expression, it considers it as a path separator. If there is a backslash at the very end of the expression, then it signifies directory matching.

Again though, for matching `->` you should be able to just use those characters directly in the filter. FastCopy doesn't consider a period as a special character either.

Both of the following filter expression would match only *files* that include the `->` at the end of the filename itself. They will not match directories since there is no trailing backslash. I don't believe you need to specify the drive letter, but if that's required then just add the `C:\` at the beginning.

```
filename.txt ->
```

and

```
filename.txt\ ->
```

Comment: I'm trying to use FastCopy, which says it will use Unix patterns.

Comment: I can't make sense of FastCopy, I read over the documentation, I tried various patterns, but it never matches the "filename.txt ->" one.  It does, however, find the "filename.txt\ ->"  The one with the slash in it.

Comment: Does `filename.txt ->*` match it?